# Python modifying binary file

Tags: python, binary-data

Okay without getting into the weeds too much. I a trying to take a binary file and read in one byte at a time, convert it to 4 bits and merge it with the next byte I read and convert to 4 bits to re-create a new byte.

I am doing this by reading a byte value comparing it to a look up table which takes the min and max values and divides by 16 for my "slots". Then looking at the value one by one and storing the new value (0-15 binary for 4 bits) based on those slots, shifting that number and then XOR with the next byte I read in as I did the first byte I read.

My program appears to be working and writing 1's and 0's but I think it's storing them as a string and not binary. Any ideas?

```
import sys
import binascii

def converttwobytes(value1, value2):
    newvalue = 0
    newvalue = newvalue ^ value1
    newvalue1 = newvalue << 4
    newvalue = newvalue1 ^ value2
    return newvalue


if (len(sys.argv) != 3):
    print ('\n\n\nPlease enter 3 parameters: the file name to run, a file to read, a file to write to and try again, example: python prgm1.py read.txt write.txt\n\n\n')
else:
    readfile = sys.argv[1]
    writefile = sys.argv[2]
    with open(readfile, "rb") as binary_file:
    # Read the whole file at once
    data = binary_file.read()
    length = len(data)

    framelength = 16


    # Seek position set to 0 and read header of 21 bytes
    binary_file.seek(0)  # Go to beginning
    header = binary_file.read(21)
    counter = 21
    with open(writefile, 'wb') as writeline:
        writeline.write(header + '\n')

        for filesize in range(counter,length,16):
            #latest seek value
            binary_file.seek(filesize)
            maxnum = 0
            minnum = 0
            for frame in range(0,framelength):
                value = ord(binary_file.read(1))
                if frame == 0:
                    minnum = value
                    maxnum = minnum
                elif value > maxnum:
                    maxnum = value
                elif value < minnum:
                    minnum = value


            totalspread = maxnum - minnum
            binary_file.seek(filesize)
            # 16 is max number of 4 bits binary
            bucketsize = (totalspread/16)

            #reset seek back to frame start location
            binary_file.seek(filesize)
            newlist = []
            for frame in range(0,framelength):
                value = ord(binary_file.read(1))
                result =0
                if value < (minnum+bucketsize):
                    result = 0
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*2)):
                    result =1
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*3)):
                    result =2
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*4)):
                    result =3
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*5)):
                    result =4
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*6)):
                    result =5
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*7)):
                    result =6
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*8)):
                    result =7
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*9)):
                    result =8
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*10)):
                    result =9
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*11)):
                    result =10
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*12)):
                    result =11
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*13)):
                    result =12
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*14)):
                    result =13
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*15)):
                    result =14
                elif value < (minnum+(bucketsize*16)):
                    result =15

                newlist.append(result)
            newlist.reverse()
            i = 0
            while i < len(newlist):
                firstfour = newlist.pop()
                lastfour = newlist.pop()

                newbyte = converttwobytes(firstfour, lastfour)

                writeline.write(bin(newbyte)[2:].zfill(8))
                i = i + 2
```

This is a sample of the file I am trying to encode and decode:

```
 P5

 256 256

 255




ææææåææäèééçæèèèæçèêæèééèéëêêçëêêêéêëéëêëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëéëëéèèåæåäåäæéàãäáãäáãàââããäááâãâäâäääãääääæäçëéêéèéééææèèåçèäåååèãæääåèæçæçèåçæçæåææãâáàäææäâßäääæäáããâááâãÞàáæâÞáÞßàÚÛÜÜÝßÞÝßÛßàÙÝßßÛÜÛÛÝÜÚÛÚ×ÕÚÙÖÚÖÓÖÔÓÔÕÒÕÒÔÔÓÓÒÒÏÏÐÍÌÍÑËÉÉÆÊÍÇçëéçéçéäãèçèççêèææèçæåæåèèèæææçæèçèêéççêéèèæéêëéêêëëëëéëëéëêééëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëëéëèêèææèêéééäåååãäååääåæäãããäãâååããæçåçççèèèçææèèæççéçèæåææèèæææãåæçåæåçæèæçèåçèéçäãåãääßääåäåãäãåããäãåâáÞáßßÞâßßÜÞ
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about `bytes` and "bytes-like objects".

Answer (score 0):

The imput you will recive will be an String, so you need to transform it:

```
bin(int(binascii.hexlify(str(result)), 16))
```

Comment: That puts each byte in the file like this 0b1100000. This is not accomplishing what I want because the original file was 66kb and now it's 264 kb. I was originally taking an image file reading it in byte by byte and then taking two bytes and combining them. So I should have almost half the amount of bytes now if it was successful.